# Se puede mostrar valor de variables Typescript en HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

Ejemplo Typescript:

```
var Año = '20200101'
```

como puedo llamarla del lado de HTML

El año es: y que aparezca el valor del Año?

Ejemplo actual:

```
public initialDateReport: string = '';
 if (this.fechaini != null) {
      this.initialDateReport = this.fechaini.getUTCFullYear() + this.addCero(String(this.fechaini.getUTCMonth() + 1)) + this.addCero(String(this.fechaini.getUTCDate()));
    }
```

esa es mi llamada y se adigna a la variable initialDateReport

del lado de html:

```
<div>Fechas del: {{initialDateReport}} al {{initialDateReport}}</div>
```

Comment: TS te compila a JS nativo, ¿para qué necesitas directamente el .ts en tu navegador, comprendiendo que este solo entiende html, css y js?

Comment: Respecto a lo que pregunto, me refiero a llamar el valor, intenté hacerlo por interpolación pero no respeta el valor, la fecha la recupero de una consulta del lado de Typescript las guardo en una variable y deseo mostrar ese valor que ingreso el usuario en la salida de un reporte. @Aprendiz

Comment: Agrega el HTML de como lo estas tratando de interpolar

Comment: @Aprendiz echo.

Comment: Prueba a mover ese codigo al AfterViewInit. La otra opcion seria a probar a ir poniendo valores mas "puros" para ver si se van modificando en tu template. Si quieres que te ayudemos a debugear el caso tendras que subir el codigo completo. Puedes usar una web como stackblitz para compartir tu ejemplo.

Comment: La parte de arriba está bien y funciona, en realidad si funciona la interpolación ,el tema en realidad radicaba en que se seteaba la variable a través de otra función. lo aclaro para no causar confusión. Nota: soy novato en angular :(